# something like gimp "fuzzy select" in python/PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have image with some object at not solid background. I want to extract this objects like in gimp using "fuzzy select". This can be an example:

http://img249.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=25750902.png

Question is what is the best way to do it using python/PIL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you would need some flood-fill algorithm (such as breadth-first-traversal) in which you stop exploring pixels with different color than black.

Wikipedia has an excellent explanation with animations and pseudo-code

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 1):

And besides, if you want to add feature like "tolerance" in Photoshop, you should apply this method [Connected-component_labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) when getting connected vertex on your graph while doing flood fill

Answer (score 1):

As of today, skimage 0.19 has a flood fill algorithm: [link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_floodfill.html)