# How to implement the magic wand function in Python

Tags: python, image, pyqt4

I have a image region labelling programme which was coded with python and library of PyQt4, I want to implement the magic wand function like photoshop and GMIP to selection a region referring a object and then to label the region. Could you tell me how to implement that or Are there some libray which can be used to deal with the issue.

Comment: There are many answers on this throughout the internet and stackoverflow. To get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754202/something-like-gimp-fuzzy-select-in-python-pil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, I have found that a [blog]: http://www.losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/  "blog of Andy Finnel"  which includes the detail of implementing such algorithm. I also found that downscaling the image that you will process and then rescale the image up is a good ideal for performance reason.